# In what sense do we "only ever observe angles, never lengths as such"?

Tags: general-relativity, measurements

The closing paragraph of [Julian Barbour's review](https://physicsworld.com/a/inside-penroses-universe/) of Penrose's *Cycles of Time* contains the following (emphasis mine):

> Despite his great attraction to conformal geometry, Penrose still
> accords length a real physical role. But **in fact we only ever
> observe angles, never lengths as such**.

Would someone kindly explain what this means? (E.g., is using a yardstick not "observing a length as such"?)

Comment: Length depends on the observer. Look at length contraction for example. Angles do not.

Comment: @Jan2103 that is factually incorrect. Angles are not invariant under Lorentz transformations.

Comment: That is true. My bad!

Comment: I'm not sure how it is possible to answer your question. For once, I completely disagree with the claim. Length are definitely measurable – we all know what the distance from the Earth to the Sun is, what the diameter of the hydrogen atom is, the values of masses of elementary particles (in quantum field theory, mass acts as inverse length).

Comment: I agree with @Prof.Legolasov's comment. Notice that Barbour's sentence just before the one quoted in the question starts with "Let me end provocatively..." Maybe Barbour has some kind of non-mainstream theory in mind, but then this might be a question that only Barbour can answer. If asking Barbour directly isn't an option, then maybe you can find some clues in Barbour's own research papers, like this one: https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0183.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly - Thanks for that link -- it seems to contain (on p. 24) the answer to my question: "Moreover, distances are not directly observable. To measure an interval, we must lay a ruler adjacent to it. If the interval and the ruler subtend the same angle at our eye, we say that they have the same length. This is one reason for thinking that angles are more fundamental than distances; another is that they are dimensionless."

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov, Re, "We all know what the distance from the Earth to the Sun is." Nobody ever directly measured that distance. Rather, we know what distance solves various different equations that are set up using laws of mechanics and parameters obtained by measuring the time of flight of radar signals bouncing off of the inner planets, the time it takes various astronomical objects to trace out certain angles in the sky, etc. More recently, we've developed the ability to bounce radar signals off of the Sun itself, but even then, we're measuring time, and only inferring distance.

Comment: @r.e.s. That's a pretty weak objection though. You could just as well say that you can't measure angles either, you just lay protractors adjacent to them. In fact, in practice angles are often measured by directly measuring lengths and then using trigonometry.

Comment: @r.e.s. I don't think you should take Barbour's statement too seriously. It's just a philosophical opinion, you are free to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

Physics is local; length is an intrinsically nonlocal concept. The only way to determine length is to take data from spacelike separated locations, combine it at a point, and infer the length from "afar". The laws of nature never deal with length directly.

Angles can in principle be measured locally. The dot product of any two unit four-vectors is the cosine or hyperbolic cosine of the angle between them. If all observables are Lorentz scalars then they're all vector lengths and angles, or products of them.

On the other hand it's a clear fact about the world that objects from protons to galaxies tend to maintain consistent sizes over long periods of time, though the reasons they do it are pretty complicated. Without context, I'm not sure what point Barbour was trying to make.

Comment: The laws of nature may be local, but not all observables are. For example, the proper time along a geodesic is a valid observable with the dimension of time = length in GR. It depends on the fundamental variables (local fields) through an integral.